# View counts on Data Explorer overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, views

Apparently, the view counts on Data Explorer don't abbreviate to `12k` (etc.) like other sites, and this, of course, causes problems:

[image]

As you can clearly* see, the view count has overflown the gray background box.

---

*For some values of `clearly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. I've gone ahead and [tamed that number](https://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=33286828d1bc2b9826e499f32d1cc801cff2e6c3) now, but it might be a little bit before the changes are pulled and deployed to the live site.